# Can't find parent for StyleData when using Robolectric in Android Studio with AppCompat

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-testing

I have an Android project which uses:

- Android Studio Gradle structure
- Android AppCompat library
- Robolectric for testing

Testing without involving any Activity (e.g. just asserting 1 == 1), works fine. But, when I use activity creates the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? can't find parent for StyleData{name='Theme_Sanactbar', parent='@style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar'}
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getParent(ShadowAssetManager.java:365)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getAttrValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:350)
```

I tried https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/979 but it creates the same result.

---

FYI:

This is my PROJECT/build.gradle

```groovy
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // For Robolectric
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/rockerhieu/mvn-repo/raw/master/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
        classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // For Robolectric
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
}
```

And this is my PROJECT/app/build.gradle

```groovy
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-test' // Robolectric

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id.web.michsan.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    if (System.getenv("KEYSTORE") != null) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))
                storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
                keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            if (System.getenv("KEYSTORE") != null) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    /* For the sake of butterknife */
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test') // For Robolectric
    }
}

ext {
    androidApiVersion = '19.1.0'
    butterknifeVersion = '4.0.1'
    robotiumVersion = '5.0.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + androidApiVersion
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + androidApiVersion
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(project(':core')) {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: '../core/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:' + butterknifeVersion
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:' + butterknifeVersion
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:' + robotiumVersion

    // For Robolectric
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'

    compile 'com.mopub.mobileads:mopub-android:+@aar'
}


// Robolectric: Add this definition in order to only include files that are suffixed with Test.class and set the max heap size
androidTest {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}
```

Comment: What version of Robolectric are you using?

Comment: I'll try to check it this evening

Comment: It is strange. I've just tried with my pet project (https://github.com/emartynov/UrlSetter) and it works. I also see the Theme definition in `build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/values.xml`

Comment: I think, your project structure is not an Android Studio's structure or at least not of structure for 2 modules or more like mine (mine has app and core modules). Single module like dackle-gradle pet app does work.

Comment: yes, but I don't think this should be the issue

Comment: I think I should go with absolute path first. And see if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After debugging the Robolectric source, I know that I need to create project.properties file.

Assuming you're using Android Studio project structure, location of the file is `PROJECT_X/app/src/main/project.properties`

The content is

```
android.library.reference.1=/../../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0
```

This is because Robolectric's `AndroidManifest.getBaseDir()` gives you `/path/into/AndroidStudioProjects/PROJECT_X/app/src/main`.

So, this base directory is appended with the reference location. On this case, I can ensure that `/path/into/AndroidStudioProjects/PROJECT_X/app/src/main` **+** `/../../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0` gives me a directory which contains AndroidManifest.xml of the appcompat library.

Comment: my case is /../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.0.1

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was to update to `roboletric:2.4-SNAPSHOT` and make sure that you have your test class in the same "package" as the class under test.

Also my test class needed this config annotation:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18)
```

**I did not need a `project.properties` file**

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4-SNAPSHOT') {
        //excludes here
    }
}
```

Additionally, I had to be sure I had the following task in gradle to avoid verify errors (only semi related)

```
/**
 * Fixes: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1186
 * Java 7 and 8 have strict compiler verification, this doesn't apply to Android
 * Our error was related to AppCompat not Play Svcs, but it was the same error
 */
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    def taskName = theTask.name.toString()
    if ("testDebug".toString().equals(taskName)) {
        /**
         * Listen for when robolectric adds the 'testDebug' task and when it does, add the -noverify
         * option to that task's jvmArgs.  This allows us to turn off byte code verification when
         * running our unit tests.
         */
        theTask.jvmArgs('-noverify')
    }
}
```